# Error when using Select Field from Material-ui with Redux Form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-form

I abstracted the SelectField material-ui component and attempted to plug it into my Redux Form but it threw an error I can't seem to get around. I believe my React component class is implemented correctly, but the error message says otherwise.

Error below:

```
Error in ./src/components/new_entry_copy.js
Syntax error: Unexpected token, expected } (37:21)

  35 | 
  36 | class MaterialUiForm extends Component {
> 37 |   constructor(props) {
     |                      ^
  38 |     super(props)
  39 |     this.state = {
  40 |       category: null,

 @ ./src/components/app.js 28:22-61
```

It seems weird, because the TextFields renders without a problem. This only seems to be happen with the SelectField components.

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { reduxForm, Field, Form } from "redux-form";
import { createEntry } from "../actions/index";
import TextField from "material-ui/TextField";
import SelectField from "material-ui/SelectField";
import MenuItem from "material-ui/MenuItem";
import injectTapEventPlugin from "react-tap-event-plugin";
import RaisedButton from "material-ui/RaisedButton";


injectTapEventPlugin();

const renderTextField = ({ input,label }) => (
    <TextField
      { ...input }
      hintText="Who did you ask?"
      floatingLabelText={ label }
      floatingLabelFixed={ true }
    />

);

const renderSelectField = ({ input,label,children }) => (
    <SelectField
      { ...input }
      floatingLabelText={ label }
      floatingLabelFixed={true}
      value={this.state.outcome}
      onChange={(event, index, value) => this.setState({outcome: value })}>
      children={children} />
  );
)


class MaterialUiForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      category: "",
      outcome: ""
    }

  };

  onSubmit(props) {
    console.log(props);
  };

  render() {
    const { handleSubmit } = this.props;
    return (
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.onSubmit.bind(this))}>
        <div className="ask">
          <Field name="ask" component={renderTextField} label="Ask" />
        </div>

        <div className="askee">
          <Field name="askee" component={renderTextField} label="Askee" />
        </div>

        <div className="outcome">
          <Field name="outcome" component={renderSelectField} label="Outcome">
            <MenuItem value="Accepted" primaryText="Accepted" />
            <MenuItem value="Rejected" primaryText="Rejected" />
          </Field>
        </div>

        <RaisedButton label="Submit" type="submit" primary={true} />
      </form>
    )
  }
}

export default reduxForm({
  form: 'MaterialUiForm'  // a unique identifier for this form
})(MaterialUiForm)
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out!

I forgot to close the `<SelectField>`.

This variable:

```
const renderSelectField = ({ input,label,children }) => (
    <SelectField
      { ...input }
      floatingLabelText={ label }
      floatingLabelFixed={true}
      value={this.state.outcome}
      onChange={(event, index, value) => this.setState({outcome: value })}>
      children={children} />
  );
)
```

Should be:

```
const renderSelectField = ({ input,label,children }) => (
    <SelectField
      { ...input }
      floatingLabelText={ label }
      floatingLabelFixed={true}
      value={this.state.outcome}
      onChange={(event, index, value) => this.setState({outcome: value })}>
      children={children}>
    </SelectField>
  );
)
```